# Adding more information to InvalidOperationException line

Tags: c#, azure-application-insights

I am trying to learn how to throw exceptions.

Currently when I do the following

```
        try
        {
            throw new InvalidOperationException("TEST");
        }
        catch
        {
                throw;
        }
```

When I look into AI the exception comes like this:#

InvalidOperationException

[image]

with a message "Test"

How do I get it to throw something like the below?

```
System.InvalidOperationException: TEST at test.Program.Main
```

[image]

Comment: `Exception` comes with a `StackTrace` property https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.exception.stacktrace?view=net-5.0 that indicates where it was thrown from. Is this what you are looking for?

Comment: adding this extra information into application insights logs?

Answer (score 0):

As moreON said in the comment, you could get where the exception thrown from with [`Exception.StackTrace`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.exception.stacktrace?view=net-5.0) property.

```
try
{
    throw new InvalidOperationException("TEST");
}
catch(InvalidOperationException e)
{
    throw new InvalidOperationException(e.Message + e.StackTrace);
}
```

**Or** you can get the current project name/file name/method name/line number. And it throws like this: `System.InvalidOperationException: ProjetName.FileName.MethodName(LineNumber): TEXT`.

```
private static string Log(string text,
                [CallerFilePath] string file = "",
                [CallerMemberName] string member = "",
                [CallerLineNumber] int line = 0)
{
    return Assembly.GetCallingAssembly().GetName().Name+"."+Path.GetFileName(file)+"."+member+"("+line + "): " + text;
}

// throw exception
try
{
    
    throw new InvalidOperationException(Log("Test"));
}
catch(InvalidOperationException e)
{
    throw;
}
```

Comment: If my reply is helpful, please accept it as answer, thank you.